# hockeyapp not understand crash logs

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, hockeyapp

Im using hockeyapp to get crash reports.
How can i understand at which class/method/line did my application crashed ?

[image]

Comment: Upload your build with dSYM symbol file

Comment: Follow the steps on this link: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/how-to-manually-upload-and-symbolicate-a-crash

Answer (score 6):

To get the most use out of crash reports from HockeyApp, you should upload your dSYM symbol files to the site. This will give you fully symbolicated crash logs where it clearly states the file, method and line number where your crash is occurring.

[image: Screenshot of the HockeyApp website]

For detailed instructions on how to do that, see [this support article](http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/ios/3.8.2/docs/docs/HowTo-Upload-Symbols.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some where you set/assign image as a parameter/argument. and this image is nil in  case but this image should not be nil.

for example:

```
-(void)setImageOnExampleView:(UIImage*)image{
  //if here is image = nil and if you call this method anywhere such crash will happen
  [yourImageView setImage:image];
}
```

So, to detect where this crash occur, in possible places, where you are setting image; you should set "Break Point and debug in which classes of which method this crash occur.

Comment: OP Q is more about symbolicated crashlog and that concrete crash is not probably important