# Get exception exact line number in Hockey App for UWP Application

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, hockeyapp

I have UWP App associated with hockey app, in the crash analytics I am getting exception logs as `Exception Type:  System.NullReferenceException` and it's also mentioning method name in which that exception was fired.

Is there any way to get the exact line number which throws that exception inside that method?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065874/815938), the answer is for Mac version, but the idea is the same: you need to upload pdb files to translate the offset to line number.

Comment: @kennyzx Thanks, but I already have build associated with it via VSTS. Do I have to upload .pdb symbols as well? And do .dysm relates for UWP as well?

Comment: Is [this](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application) helpful?

Comment: Thanks, I will go through the process mentioned in that doc and see if I can get more info in the crash logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to symbolicate crashes for .NET UWP applications you need to upload symbol (*.pdb) files to `HockeyApp`. Follow [the instructions](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-upload-symbols-for-uwp-application) to upload symbols for UWP application.

Symbol files (*.pdb) are created from the source code during compilation, they contain the information required to translate memory address to human readable format (like file name / line number).